# How to differ two different items on the same list (base of contents)

Tags: usability, interaction-design, lists

I've **content bases** that can be exported and imported into other environments. **A content base is a set of specific files.

When I import a content base from another environment, my source files are added and the same file names are renamed. So when I remove that content base, the added files are deleted and the renamed files are deleted. This behavior cannot happen with content bases created by my environment. There my source files cannot be removed, only the list item of the content base.

How can I distinguish them visually?
My content base that I created can be exported to another via download, but I can't remove my source files.
Imported content bases removed from the list can remove imported files.

[image: Insert image description here]

Comment: How about an icon or a separate column (environment: Your environment, Different environment)? You could also warn the user when they delete the content base.

Comment: The concept is not 100% clear. You might need to explain why the user needs this for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear with the question. But based on what I understand, I would suggest that overwriting a source file without governance is dangerous, either add a governance where someone oversees it and approves/rejects or keep versioning with multiple versions available and the admin having capability to go back to a previous version.(number of versions that you store can be given a time stamp of sya last 2 weeks or one month/yr)

Adding a prefix to any external file/content can help in distinction, and based on prefix you can logic it to some color